# How to pass output folder parameter to jasmine JUnitHtmlReporter via jasmine.json

Tags: jasmine

I see in the docs of Jasmine JUnit reporter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-xml-reporter that I can pass parameters of output location and `--junitreport` however I'm not using the command line I'm using `jasmine.json`.

I could not figure out how to pass the `--output` and `--junitreport` parameters via jasmine.json at least I don't see any output files this is what I'm trying:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "src/test",
  "spec_files": [
    "ts/**/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "reporters": [
    {
      "name": "jasmine-reporters#JUnitXmlReporter",
      "options": {
        "output": "../dist"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas how to pass the `--output` and `--junitreport` parameters to this library?